# Convert Oracle (Cross Join?) to Netezza when using comma separated table list instead of JOIN keywords

Tags: oracle, join, netezza, cross-join

Below is is some Oracle PL/SQL code to join tables without using actual JOIN keywords.  This looks like a cross join?  How would I convert to Netezza SQL code?  That's where I'm stuck.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLE_A A, TABLE_A B
WHERE A.X = 'Y' AND A.PATH LIKE '/A/A/A'
AND B.X = 'Z' AND B.PATH LIKE '/B/B/B';
```

Oracle Cross Join:

http://www.sqlguides.com/sql_cross_join.php

Here's what I tried so far:

```
SELECT *
from TABLE_A A
cross join (
    select * from TABLE_A
) B
WHERE 
  A.X = 'Y' AND A.PATH LIKE '/A/A/A'
  AND B.X = 'Z' AND B.PATH LIKE '/B/B/B';
```

## EDIT:

a_horse_with_no_name:

When I use either syntax in Netezza for the COUNT(*) in the very beginning, it works and returns a count of 60, which matches the first query above when running in Oracle.  Without the WHERE clause in Netezza returns 125316 results, which matches the first query above when running in Oracle.  When I use either syntax in Netezza for the SELECT * in the very beginning, I get error

> ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  Record size 70418 exceeds internal limit of 65535 bytes'

Comment: simple as in INNER?  X is a column name.

Comment: (your edit `= Y`  to `= 'Y'` changed the meaning of the query) The Oracle SQL should work like that in any SQL database (although the cross join does look **very** strange to me). But if you do want to replace it with a `cross join` it would be `from table_a a cross join table_b b where ...`

Comment: I don't know Netezza, but the error message seems to indicate that your `select *` is selecting too many _columns_ ("record size"). Try to select **only** those columns that you really need, not all columns from both tables. A "proper" cross join syntax won't change that, because you will _still_ select all columns.

Comment: Thanks!  Selecting individual columns worked.  The * must have been ambiguous.  So this is in fact a cross join (in first query)?

Comment: Yes it is. (When I claimed it isn't you had a condition on two columns (`A.X = Y`) in your query which I suspected to be a join condition between the tables. But as you changed that to a comparison with a constant `a.x = 'Y'` it couldn't be a join condition any more and thus it **is** a cross join and not an inner join with an implicit join condition. Another good example why using an explicit join is better - even for a cross join

Comment: Just as a side note, Netezza is a data warehousing database product (based on Postgres SQL) that IBM sells for millions of dollars.  It's wicked fast!  It's meant for Big Data and data warehouse storage (analytics).  I've run queries in Netezza in under a minute that take days to run in Oracle.  It's scary!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to use explicit columns in Netezza when doing a CROSS JOIN.  Using SELECT * throws the error as indicated in my question EDIT.  Also had to escape the '%' character by escaping nothing.  Thank you a_horse_with_no_name.  Cheers!  "Where everybody knows your name."  ;-)

```
select A.CODE, B.CODE, LOWER(A.DIM), LOWER(B.DIM)
FROM TABLE_A A
cross join TABLE_A B
WHERE A.PATH LIKE '\A\A\A%' ESCAPE '' AND A.X = 'Y'
AND B.PATH LIKE '\B\B\B%' ESCAPE '' AND B.X = 'Y'
```